# How can I pass in a variable to a std::async?

Tags: c++, c++11, stdasync

How can I pass in a vector to an async call like so??

```
std::vector<int> vectorofInts;
vectorofInts.push_back(1);
vectorofInts.push_back(2);
vectorofInts.push_back(3);

std::async([=]
{
    //I want to access the vector in here, how do I pass it in
    std::vector<int>::iterator position = std::find(vectorofInts.begin(), vectorofInts.end(), 2);
    //Do something 
}
```

Comment: What caused you to ask this? Is something specific going wrong?

Comment: I think change the capture to by reference `[&]` should do it for you.

Comment: @doctorlove When I use [=] the std::find gives me an error: Error 1 error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_Vector_const_iterator<_Myvec>' to 'std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>'

Comment: @HarryBoy: That's because the vector is `const` (since the lambda isn't `mutable`), so `find` returns a `const_iterator`. Change the type of `position` to `std::vector<int>::const_iterator` or `auto`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're already capturing it by value in the lambda, by specifying `[=]` as the capture list. So, within the lambda body, you can use `vectorofInts` to refer to that copy. You could specify `[vectorofInts]` if you want to be more explicit; just `[=]` will automatically capture any variable that's used by the lambda.

However, you can't modify captured values unless the lambda is `mutable`. So the vector is treated as `const`, and `find` returns a `const_iterator`. As the error message (posted in a comment) says, you can't convert `iterator` to `const_iterator`, so change your variable type to `std::vector<int>::iterator` or `auto`.

If you want to access the vector itself, not a copy, then capture by reference by specifying `[&]`, or `[&vectorofInts]` if you want to be explicit. But be careful what you do with it if you share it between threads like that, and make sure you don't destroy it until the asyncronous access has completed.